# Stacked Bar Charts ggplot2 error

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is in a dataframe called df_M that looks like this:

```
    Var1 Var2 Freq
1     A    2    4
2     B    2   18
3     C    2   32
4     D    2    0
5     E    2    3
6     F    2    0
7     G    2    0
8     A    3    1
9     B    3   26
10    C    3    0
11    D    3    0
12    E    3    0
13    F    3   15
14    G    3    0
15    A    4   43
16    B    4    0
17    C    4    0
18    D    4    0
19    E    4    0
20    F    4    0
21    G    4    0
22    A    5    0
23    B    5    0
24    C    5    0
25    D    5   25
26    E    5    0
27    F    5    0
28    G    5   12
29    A    6    2
30    B    6    7
31    C    6    0
32    D    6    0
33    E    6    0
34    F    6    0
35    G    6    0
36    A    7    2
37    B    7    0
38    C    7    0
39    D    7    0
40    E    7    0
41    F    7    0
42    G    7    0
43    A    8    0
44    B    8    0
45    C    8    0
46    D    8    0
47    E    8    0
48    F    8    1
49    G    8    0
50    A    9    0
51    B    9    0
52    C    9    1
53    D    9    0
54    E    9    0
55    F    9    0
56    G    9    0
57    A   10    0
58    B   10    0
59    C   10    0
60    D   10    0
61    E   10    0
62    F   10    1
63    G   10    0
```

I am using the following code to create a stacked bar chart:

```
ggplot(data=df_M, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq, fill=Var1))+geom_bar()
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

I have ensured however that Freq is an integer:

```
> class(df_M$Freq)
[1] "integer"
> class(df_M$Var1)
[1] "factor"
> class(df_M$Var2)
[1] "factor"
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. The nature of my data seems to be the same as the one in the tutorial [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3256_bb10db1440724dac8fa40da5e658ada5.html)

Comment: Try adding `stat = "identity"` to your `geom_bar` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `Freq` is already the count for your bar heigth. You have to set `stat = "identity"` then because by default it is `stat = "count"` and no `y` in `aes` must be provided as `stat_count` is applied on `x` and `y` is calculated. It is the meaning of ther error.

For your data:

```r
ggplot(data=DT, aes(x = Var2, y = Freq, fill = Var1)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: Stack barplot]